# Tikzlibrary calligraphy error

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary, calligraphy

The code below uses the Ti*k*Z library `calligraphy`, but throws an error:

`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrentname ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

A regular Ti*k*Z brace works as expected.

Probably missing something basic, but so far a solution eludes me.

Update: Using MacTeX 2019, updated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\barbox}

\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\barbox}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        1&2&3\\
        A&B&C\\
        X&Y&Z
    \end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}

\tikz{%
    \node (z) {\usebox{\barbox}};
    %% This works:
    %\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]
    %% This gives error:
    %% Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrentname ' and I am
    %% going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
    \draw[decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=2mm,mirror}]
        (z.south east) -- (z.north east);
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [calligraphy manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3/calligraphy_doc.pdf) says on page 7:

> If a TikZ/PGF decorations library is loaded prior to this library,
>   then the calligraphy library defines some decorations that use the
>   calligraphic paths, specifically with the copperplate nib. The current
>   decorations are: • calligraphic brace for a brace. [...]

So: first load `decorations.pathreplacing`, then `calligraphy`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\barbox}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\barbox}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        1&2&3\\
        A&B&C\\
        X&Y&Z
    \end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}

\tikz{%
    \node (z) {\usebox{\barbox}};
    \draw[decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=2mm,mirror}]
        (z.south east) -- (z.north east);
}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Well done. Works.